# One Statement object, multiple executeUpdates

Tags: java, jdbc

Is recommended to create just one Statement object and execute multiple executeUpdate() on it?

```
// Vantages/drawbacks of this solution?
conn.setAutocommit(false);

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate('[ANY_INSERT_SQL]');
stmt.executeUpdate('[ANY_INSERT_SQL]');
stmt.executeUpdate('[ANY_INSERT_SQL]');

conn.commit();
```

Or is better one Statement object for each executeUpdate:

```
// Vantages/drawbacks of this solution?
conn.setAutocommit(false);

Statement stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
stmt1.executeUpdate('[ANY_INSERT_SQL]');
Statement stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
stmt2.executeUpdate('[ANY_INSERT_SQL]');
Statement stmt3 = conn.createStatement();
stmt3.executeUpdate('[ANY_INSERT_SQL]');

conn.commit();
```

Thanks in advance.

PS: I know PreparedStatement class and I use it often, but my doubt is about Statement usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the javadoc, A statement can have only one associated `ResultSet` object.

> The object used for executing a static
>   SQL statement and returning the
>   results it produces.
>
> By default, only one ResultSet object
>   per Statement object can be open at
>   the same time. Therefore, if the
>   reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of
>   another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects. All
>   execution methods in the Statement
>   interface implicitly close a
>   statment's current ResultSet object if
>   an open one exists.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

If you need to process multiple results sets at the same time, perhaps, more statements make sense.

Probably more often than not, you only need to use one.

Performance-wise, probably better as it keeps fewer resources active.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter, just make sure you close all statement objects.